GraphQL-WS WebSocket Connection Issue
I have a WebSocket server running on Google Cloud Run with Node. I am using graphql-ws to run the sever. I am trying to connect to the WebSocket server with my React Native client also using graphql-ws. I can connect to the server just fine in Google Cloud Run using wss with wscat. I can also connect to the server when it is running locally using ws (I'm not serving my own SSL cert but Google Cloud Run does that for me). However, for some unknown reason I cannot connect to the Google Cloud Run server from my React Native client.
Here's my server code:
    const pubsub = new PubSub();
    ...
    const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
        server: httpServer,
        path: '/graphql',
    });

    useServer({ schema, context: { pubsub } }, wsServer);
    ...

    async function publishGreetings() {
        await pubsub.publish('GREETINGS', { greetings: 'Hello every 5 seconds' });
    }

    setInterval(() => {
        publishGreetings().catch(error => {
            console.error('Failed to publish greetings:', error);
        });
    }, 5000);

Here's my React Native client connection code:
    const wsClient = createClient({
    url: wss://...,
    connectionParams: {
        reconnect: true,
    },
    connectionAckWaitTimeout: 20_000,
    retryAttempts: 5,
    retryWait: (count) => {
        Math.min(1000 * 2 ** count, 30_000);
        return new Promise(() => {});
    },
    on: {
        connected: () => console.log('WebSocket connected'),
        error: (err) => console.error('WebSocket error:', err),
        closed: () => console.log('WebSocket closed'),
    },
});

const wsLink = new GraphQLWsLink(wsClient);

const splitLink = split(
    ({ query }) => {
        const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
        return (
            definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
            definition.operation === 'subscription'
        );
    },
    wsLink,
    from([quotaLink, httpLink])
);

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: splitLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

const GREETINGS_SUBSCRIPTION = gql`
    subscription OnGreeting {
        greetings
    }
`;

client
    .subscribe({
        query: GREETINGS_SUBSCRIPTION,
    })
    .subscribe({
        next({ data }) {
            console.log('Greeting:', data.greetings);
        },
        error(err) {
            console.error('Subscription error:', err);
        },
    });

I'm confused as to why this isn't working. I would think that if I can connect with wscat then I should be able to connect with the React Native client, but it isn't connecting. Whenever I try to connect the connection closes on Chrome and on Firefox I get this error: Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://... I'm sure there must be some way to get this working, I'm guessing there must be some misconfiguration on my client but I'm not sure what it might be.
